# How do I get Windows 7 to detect the G13 joystick as an analog Joystick?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, game-controller

[image]

Windows detects the G13 joystick, as seen by the screenshot above. But it doesn't react to it; wiggling the joystick does not alter the raw values Windows receives on the calibration dialog. What do I need to do so that the joystick is usable as an analog device?

Answer (score 0):

Before the G13 will respond as a joystick, it needs to be set as a joystick in the active profile. To do this, left-click on the joystick or any of the 4 directions around it and choose "Assign Joystick" as its function.

[image]

Comment: Finally hit on the right Google search to get my answer. Hopefully this will save someone else time when they search.